# Trouble in aligning numbers?

Tags: c++, cout

I got numbers with both negative values and positive values to print. I'd like to use code as follows:

```
cout<< setw(precN+8) << showpos << scientific << setprecision(precN)
    << xval_ << " " << yval_ << " " << zval_;
```

Remove `showpos` would give something like this:

```
0.000e+00 -1.675e-01 0.000e+00
0.000e+00 9.342e-02 0.000e+00
```

As you can see the second column is not aligned at right. With `showpos` turn on, it aligns right correctly as what I want,

```
+0.000e+00 -1.675e-01 +0.000e+00
+0.000e+00 +9.342e-02 +0.000e+00
```

But I just don't want the positive sign. I tried to use `right` option, but it does not work. What have I done wrong? And how to achieve this right aligned effect without positive sign with cout?

Answer (score 0):

It would absolutely make sense to use `#include <iomanip>` and thereby use io manipulators like  `std::setw`, `std::setfill`, `std::left` and `std::right` (last two for modifying/define alignment)

It can be a pain to work with those, so if possible I would suggest you took a look at a library like [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/) for easier manipulation (printf kind of way)